# Are the two properties of a function equivalent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

$f(x)$ is a function defined on $\Bbb R^n$.

$A$: $\forall x,y$
$$
|f(y)-f(x)-\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)| \le \frac{\beta}{2}\|y-x\|_2^2
$$

$B$: $\forall x,y$
$$
\| \nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)\|_2 \le \beta \|y-x\|_2
$$

Textbook claims that $A$ and $B$ are equivalent to each other. $B \Longrightarrow A$ is easy to prove. But how to prove $A \Longrightarrow B$?

Comment: What are the continuity hypotheses in the book?